# how to fix: my background is under the menu

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I want to do a sub-menu which should not cover-up my background. How to fix it?

In the past, I've tried multiple background but it's not working.

HTML

```
<nav>
   <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li ><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- Showcase -->
<section id="showcase">
  <div class="monitor"><img src="images/monitor.png" alt="monitor"></div>
  <!-- <div class="front"><img src="images/front-end.jpg" alt="front-end"> 
  </div> -->      
</section>
```

Here the css: https://jsfiddle.net/enzoap/84hu0m3s/2/

I expect the banner image to follow the "monitor" image, 
that is, push the banner and monitor image together, and the menu is correct, I only want to fix the sub-menu, that is cover-up the banner.

[The sub-menu after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGboJ.png)

Comment: Can you post your expected image output? Or what does *follow* mean in your context?

Comment: How do you want to see your menu? Drop down boxes? Horizontally (next to each other)? Vertically (on top of each other)? And (yes) please, I'm not sure what you mean about the "front-end" and "monitor" image placement. Can you reword it?

Comment: I reword the question, I hope you understand.

Comment: image with an expected output image would be better. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for your example is to change this style:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
  display: block;
}
```

to this:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
  display: inline-block; // This is the setting on the menu before `display: none` is set, so we reset it to this when the menu is displayed.
  width: 100%; // This could also be placed into the `ul` styles
}
```

To be completely honest, I'm not 100% sure why this works, but I tested it in your JSFiddle example and it does what I believe you want it to do.